How to feed into an AWK program a series of field names and have the AWK program check files for the presence of the field name?
field-names.txt contains a list of field names:
AB_CODE
ACFT_CODE
AC_TYPE
ADD_INFO
AKA
ALT
ALT1_DESC
ALT2_DESC
ALT3_DESC

For each field name I want to print the files whose first line contains this field name (a space-separated list of fields). Here's what I tried:
At a bash command line I entered this:
cat field-names.txt | awk 'BEGIN { getline fieldname; print fieldname }
        
NR == 1 && $0 ~ /fieldname/ { print FILENAME }' **/*.TXT

That produces the wrong result. What is the correct way to do this?

To complete your question: which delimiter do you need to find your field name between? Because here ALT would match a file containing BALTIC, which is perhaps not intended...

Good catch. Delimiter: a space before and after the field name.

How many lines are there in field-names.txt ?

and how many / how big are the files? Tens/MB? Millions/PB?

Keep in mind $0 ~ /fieldname/ does look for fieldname string in line, if you wish to check $0 against regular expression stored in variable named fieldname you should write $0 ~ fieldname see Using Dynamic Regexps in User Guide for details

Another imprecision: your question looks like you may want to name the matching fields too with each file ("For each field name I want to print the files"), like: "AB_CODE: 1.TXT, 3.TXT, 5.TXT; ACFT_CODE: 2.TXT, 3.TXT; etc.", or "1.TXT: AB_CODE; 2.TXT: ACFT_CODE; 3.TXT: AB_CODE ACFT_CODE; etc.". Does it matter, or are the proposed solutions convenient (you only want the file names, as long as they have at least one field, whichever it is)? In this case, perhaps reformulate that part as "I want to print the name of the files [...] contains one or more of those field names".

Can a field name ever contain . or any other regexp metachar?

This awk solution should work for you:
awk 'FNR == NR {
   rx = (rx == "" ? "" : rx "|") $1
   next
}
FNR == 1 && " " $0 " " ~ " (" rx ") " {
   print FILENAME
}' field-names.txt **/*.TXT

First we build a regex with | between each line of field-names.txt in the first block of FNR == NR. Then we use that regex to match against each first line using that regex. We prefix and suffix each first line and regex with space to make sure we only match whole word not the partial ones.

For the sake of optimization we can do like this to construct full regex only once:
awk 'FNR == NR {
   rx = (rx == "" ? "" : rx "|") $1
   pNR = NR
   next
}
NR == pNR+1 {
   rx = " (" rx ") "
}
FNR == 1 && " " $0 " " ~ rx {
   print FILENAME
   nextfile
}' field-names.txt **/*.TXT


Explanation of the FNR == NR trick: it tests that the line number in the current file is equal to the line number in the concatenation of all files. Thus this equality only validates for the first file, which is the trick that @anubhava used to process the first file (field-names.txt, which has to be processed) differently from the others (*.TXT, which have to be searched).

@GuillaumeOutters actually, it can match later files if some earlier file(s) contained no lines - but one hopes that will not be the case here. consider: awk FNR==NR {print; exit}' /dev/null /dev/null /dev/null /etc/passwd

awk \
'BEGIN {
    # afre = All Fields RegExp
    while((getline < "field-names.txt") > 0) afre = afre ? afre"|"$0 : $0;
    if(!afre) { print "# field-names.txt should contain at least one field name" > "/dev/stderr"; exit(1); }
    afre = "(^| )("afre")( |$)";
}
$0 ~ afre { print FILENAME; }
{ nextfile; }' **/*.TXT

(afre's computation courtesy of @Ed Morton's comment)
We take the time once at the start to compute the regex for any one of all the fields looked after,
so that the main "loop" can then run at max throttle.
And as we look only in the first line, after having looked up we use a nextfile unconditionally to switch to the next input file, wether we had a match or not.
Which solution to choose?
So the difference with @anubhava 's solution (that I liked too, and voted up: for my first two bullets, which solution you choose is a matter of taste) are:

dedicate the script to the lookup (do not mix the lookup with the regex building)
use the ^ and $ to match as the first or last field
but I often use the additional spaces trick too
do nextfile wether we match or not (no point in continuing reading all lines of a file whose line 1 did not match)

Further optimization
Note that depending on the implementation of awk, the $0 ~ afre may recompile the regexp at each line (because it is a variable, it can… vary, thus awk has to check it has not changed if it wants to cache the compiled version of the regex).
As you run it by shell, you can force it to a fixed regex (more easily optimizable) with an (admitedly less readable):
awk \
'/(^| )('"`tr \\\\012 \| < field-names.txt | sed -e 's/|$//'`"')( |$)/ { print FILENAME; }
{ nextfile; }' \
**/*.TXT


You're right, I targeted a quick and dirty solution, aware of this weakness (as well as others, like an existing but empty field-names.txt), but let's go for something more error-proof.

Assuming you want to output a map of field names to the files they occur in then using any awk (untested):
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        tgtFields[$0]
        next
    }
    FNR == 1 {
        for ( fieldNr=1; fieldNr<=NF; fieldNr++ ) {
            field = $fieldNr
            if ( field in tgtFields ) {
                files[field,++numFiles[field]] = FILENAME
            }
        }
        nextfile
    }
    END {
        for ( field in tgtFields ) {
            if ( numFiles[field] == 0 ) {
                files[field,++numFiles[field]] = "* Not found *"
            }
            for ( fileNr=1; fileNr<=numFiles[field]; fileNr++ ) {
                file = files[field,fileNr]
                print field, file
            }
        }
    }
' field-names.txt **/*.TXT

That will work whether your target file names contain regexp metachars like . or not.
Change "* Not found *" to some other string or do whatever else you like to handle target fields that don't exist in any input file. If you want to use some other separator than a blank char between the field name and each associated file name, just set OFS to whatever string you prefer.

An alternative that doesn't use regex, since it appears the list of field names are just simple strings:
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        fieldnames[$0]
        next
    }
    
    FNR==1 {
        for (i=NF; i>0 && !($i in fieldnames); --i)
            ;
        if (i)
            print FILENAME
        nextfile
    }
' field-names.txt **/*.TXT


load field name list from first file
process first line of each subsequent file

check if any field is in the list
if i>0, the loop aborted early because a match was found
don't bother even looking at the remaining lines




This code also accepts field names at the start and end of a line.
